# How to listen for a key pressed even with nothing in focus

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GridPane (called workspace) with lots of different stuff in it such as a tableview, multiple buttons, and another GridPane.

I have the following code:

```
workspace.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == (KeyCode.A)) {
                System.out.println("B Pressed");
            } else if (e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == (KeyCode.B){
                System.out.println("A Pressed");
            }
});
```

Pressing A and B only works (prints out) if something is selected. For example if I click on the tableview so it's in focus or if I click one of the buttons. If nothing is in focus (by me clicking somewhere outside of a button or the tableview), pressing A or B does nothing.

Is there any way to fix this? I want it to work even if nothing is in focus.

Comment: Set the handler on the root node.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using, but make sure that you put it after you show stage. Example:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(workspace, 300, 250);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
workspace.requestFocus();
```

This should fix your issues.

Comment: if by that you mean workspace.requestFocus() then yes I've tried that. I don't have any variables/fields named root.

Comment: If workspace is your main container for components then it should work, but make sure to use workspace.requestFocus() after you show stage otherwise it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Set the handler on your root node.

```
yourRootNode.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == (KeyCode.A)) {
                System.out.println("B Pressed");
            } else if (e.isControlDown() && e.getCode() == (KeyCode.B){
                System.out.println("A Pressed");
            }
});
```